# Using javascript "this" for jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code, we can obtain value of element id as 2 differnt way and both way return resultat

```
$("#my_div").on("click", function () {
    alert( $(this).attr("id") );

    alert( this.id );
});
```

But i interest, second way, is it proper in this case? I ask this, because in code we use jquery selector  and for jquery selector, write clear javascript: **this** is justified and will it work always? or may be better use jquery  **$(this)** for jquery selector? or not differnce?

Comment: Second one is better, there is no need to create an unnecessary jQuery object for just getting the id.

Comment: @undefined unless you plan on saving the jQuery object to a variable such as `var x = $(this);` and use it later on for things that wouldn't be (easily) accessible from pure JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.id` will give you the internal DOM element property while `$(this).attr("id")` returns the value of 'id' attribute.

The alternative to `this.id` in jQuery is using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method: `$(this).prop("id")`. However, using pure `this.id` construction will be easier and faster.

Answer (score 3):

The main jQuery constructor can take a number of different types of argument.

In that context, `this` is not a selector, it is an *HTMLElementNode* (which jQuery calls an *element*).

This is perfectly OK and [documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

There is no need to spend the resources in wrapping an element in a jQuery object if you are just going to grab its ID. There aren't any compatibility problems between browsers for that.

Grabbing the `id` property of an HTMLElementNode takes less code and is faster then wrapping the whole thing in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your second way is proper.

```
$("#my_div").on("click", function () {
    // this is available within this function
    alert( this.id );
});
```

`this` refers to an `HTMLDOMElement` within the function, and wrapping that `this` within `$()` will give  you an jQuery object.

If you define another function within the `click` handler. Ex:

```
$("#my_div").on("click", function () {
    // keep reference of this
    var that = this;
    function test() {
     // this will not available here directly
     // instead of that you can use reference
     alert(that.id);
    }
});
```

And `$(this).attr('id')`, `this.id` or `$(this).prop('id')` will give you the same result.

Answer (score 1):

For choosing the best method is not always clear.

In this case you want the `this.id`, because the other solution requires much more calls behind the scenes (obvious calls to `jQuery` and `attr`).

If you need more information that mite differ from browser, you want the jQuery way.